# Concatenate Array of PDF Files Using File Paths not working

Tags: arrays, pdf, merge, aspose

I was following the Guide on "How to concatenate array of pdf using file path" on [this page](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/Concatenate+Array+of+PDF+Files+Using+File+Paths+%28Facades%29) But with no luck. 
example: Using the code

```
using Aspose.Pdf.Facades;
    string[] filesArray = new string[2];
        filesArray[0] = @"D:\MergedPDF\Ball_007811263X\baL1263x_ch01_001-029.pdf";
        filesArray[1] = @"D:\MergedPDF\Ball_007811263X\baL1263x_ch02_030-061.pdf";
        // create PdfFileEditor object
        PdfFileEditor pdfEditor = new PdfFileEditor();
        // display the resultant concatenated PDF file in 
        pdfEditor.Concatenate(filesArray, "outputfoe.pdf");
```

but it give me an error on the pdfEditor part of **pdfEditor**.Concatenate(filesArray, "outputfoe.pdf");

```
The error says: 
Error   1   The type 'System.Web.HttpResponse' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.  C:\Users\rsubedi\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MergePDFManual\MergePDFManual\Program.cs 26  13  MergePDFManual
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trying to open the web browser to display the new PDF. Try adding the assembly System.Web and see what happens

Comment: lol, thanks i was just coming here to tell people how i solved this issue but you beat me to it sir!

Comment: No problem, and not a sir.